# Python's Django or Delphi's IntraWeb?

Tags: python, django, delphi

Well, forgive me if it is an off-topic question. I have no knowledge about web programming, so I apologize in advance, if it is a stupid question. I will start to build a web based application. To be more specific, I will make a webpage which will have components like buttons, textboxes and etc. It will use a database to store information. My question is, which one is better to learn for that purpose? Python's Django or Delphi's IntraWeb? I know both Delphi and Python(although I know Delphi better).

Comment: I already know it. I have experience with delphi for 4 years(it is very long time for me, since I have began programming 5 years ago). I know it is not much used nowadays, but I like it. In contrast, I have began practicing Python for a few month. However, I have already learned to do a lot of things with it, since it is extremely easy. My point is, I can learn both Django and Intraweb(not at the same time though) :)

Comment: @Glenn - your comment is nothing but noise and FUD; I'd think with the rep you have you'd know better.

Comment: @Ken: No, it's advice based on a couple decades of experience with software development.  Advice isn't "noise" merely because you disagree with it.

Comment: @Glenn: this question is about using the Django library with Python or the IntraWeb library with Delphi, where the OP has a better understanding of Delphi than Python. It is not the right place for commenting on what language the OP should learn or not.

Comment: Flagging comments giving advice you disagree with?  That's petty and abusive.  Please grow up.  @Jeroen: Comments are a fair place for commenting on anything related to a question; *answers* are what should be kept closely on-topic.

Comment: Guys, can you please stop fighting and give advice to me? :)

Comment: Warning: Troll detected.

Comment: @Glenn, no I flagged it as noise because that's what it is; it contributes nothing to the topic at hand. It's a flamebait comment, and shouldn't be here at all.

Comment: Voted to close for "off topic", belongs on Programmers, because the answer's going to be *subjective*. You've already seen proof of that! And to provide my subjective opinion, from those two, I'd probably select... asp.net with C#. Delphi's web offering never convinced me and I don't use python for anything that's going to be maintained for a while because of it's syntactically relevant whitespace.

Comment: A page of comments *about* a comment is noise; the comment itself is not.  @Azad: You generally won't get much help with "framework vs. framework" questions here; it's too broad a question.

Comment: @Cosmin Prund, it wouldn't be wise to learn a new programming language, in my opinion

Comment: I wonder if people are even aware that they're *censoring ideas they don't like* when they flag comments.  It has no place whatsoever on a community-driven site.  To make sure people are actually recognizing this unpleasant fact when they flag a comment, I repeat: Don't waste your time learning Delphi.

Comment: @Azad, the language is never the big problem, the framework is, and you'll be learning a new framework any way.

Comment: @Cosmin Prund, I can learn the framework as a work on my project. I could even start coding tomorrow if I knew which is the right choice(django vs. intraweb). However, learning a new language will probably take me at least a month.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't know Django, but do know IntraWeb.

You indicate you want to create a kind of data-entry application.

For that IntraWeb is suited as it is meant for writing web applications, not for web-sites, and it uses the same concept as a regular Delphi VCL application: a form designer, with a Delphi unit underneath that has the code.

So if you know how to write a Delphi VCL appliation, learning IntraWeb is easy.

There are a few things you should note when writing web apps in general (in any development environment):

1. web apps can be run by a number
   of users at the same time, so you
   need to be aware on when they can
   interfere with each other much more
   than in a regular single user
   Windows app
2. you don't know when a
   user stops using your application: a
   user might just close the browser in
   stead of formally pressing a button
   that it is stopping your app

For 1 and 2, usually you perform some way of session management, and a time out that expires stale sessions.

Since I don't know about Python or Django, I can't assess if that combination is easier than IntraWeb on Delphi.

--jeroen